# Replacing a single element in a tuple nested within a list - Is their a better way?

Tags: python, list, nested, tuples

Edit - I want to change the value of a tuple nested in a list, at a specific position
eg changed nestedTuple[1][1] change to 'xXXXXx'

I have come up with this code, that works, but it just seems very 'Un-pure!'

- Convert to a list - change - convert to tuple - insert back into list

I ASSuME that it would be very demanding on resources.

Could anyone please advise me if their is a better way?

```
>>> nestedTuple= [('a','b','c'), ('d','e','f'), ('g','h','i')]
>>> tempList = list(nestedTuple[1])
>>> tempList[1] = 'xXXXXx'
>>> nestedTuple[1] = tuple(tempList)
>>> print nestedTuple
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'xXXXXx', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i')]
```

Comment: If you want to change values in your tuple, why don't you use lists rather than tuples?

Comment: and access to correct index instead create temp objects: nestedTuple[1][1] = 'xXXXx' ?

Comment: Yes I agree! :( However this is screen scraped data, acquired using "urllib" and regular expressions. It is what it is.

Comment: Thought I would time mine 0.00282470565791 - so 2nd place to me :)
although I admit, on looks its a 'dogs dinner'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use slicing.

```
>>> i = 1
>>> nestedTuple = [('a','b','c'), ('d','e','f'), ('g','h','i')]
>>> nestedTuple[1] = nestedTuple[1][:i] + ('xXXXXx', ) + nestedTuple[1][i+1:]
>>> nestedTuple
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'xXXXXx', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i')]
```

Comment: Cheers Vishnu, you have just highlighted the flaw in my question. I wanted to change at a position not a value eg changed nestedTuple[1][1]

Comment: Another beautiful answer, cheers - but which is best? - I have done a little test and iterated the process 1000 times and measured the time = 0.00249214262687

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
nested_tuple[1] = tuple('XXXXX' if i==1 else x for i, x in enumerate(nested_tuple[1]))
```

Note that tuples aren't meant to be changed, so one liners aren't going to be very clean.

Comment: Compared to my attempt - its Beautiful!

Comment: Thanks for the compliment :)

Comment: I have done a little test and iterated the process 1000 times and measured the time = 0.00348103061689 - Sorry, Vishnu got the tick, although yours looks better (probably because I'm a numpty and cannot follow the code, I'll work on it :) )

Comment: @FloggedHorse now worries but please mention performance in the question next time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many changes you want to make in your nestedTuple and depending on downstream in your program. You may want to built a nestedList from your nestedTuple

```
nestedList = [list(myTuple) for myTuple in nestedTuple]
```

and then do:

```
nestedList[x][y] = 'truc'
```

and then make a new nestedTuple if needed

Otherwise you should profile this

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is data structure that you are getting.   Performance aside it would make for much cleaner and readable code to change the data to nested list,   do the manipulation, and if you need to write it back to convert it back to nested tuple.   May be suboptimal in terms of speed, but  that might not be the limiting factor for your application.

```
nestedTuple= [('a','b','c'), ('d','e','f'), ('g','h','i')]
nestedList = [list(x) for x in nestedTuple]
```

now you can use normal list slicing and assigning

```
nestedList[1][1] = ['xxxxXXxxx']
```

if you need the data back in original nested tuple format use the one liner:

```
nestedTuple = [tuple(x) for x in nestedList]
```

most readable and least likely to contain bugs if your data structure grows and your slicing becomes more complex.

Answer (score -1):

Very purpose to use tuples is its immutable means once the tuple is created the values cannot be changed. In your case the best way will be to use nested lists i.e., as shown below

```
>>> nestedList = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]
```

Now to change the element 'e' in the list to 'xxxx' you can use as shown below

```
>>> nestedList[1][1] = 'xxxx'
```

Comment: Cheers swamydkv, but thats a list nested in a list, not a tuple nested in a list

Comment: yes that is what I am telling, for the above one it is best to use list in a list not tuples. Can you please tell me why tuple is used.

Comment: Screen scraped data, acquired using "re" and "regular expressions" - its what you get when you use ...   `data= re.findall(regularExpression, retrievedData,)`